# downloading all links on webpage

Tags: python, web-scraping, automation, pyautogui

I'm interested in writing a python script that'll download all of the YouTube Audio Library: https://www.youtube.com/audiolibrary/music

I'd like to be able to grab the following. Song Title, Artist, Genre, and Mood.

I don't need a written solution to this but would appreciate being pointed in the correct direction for being able to do this.

So far my only solution is to use PyAutoGUI.

Comment: Please attempt to solve the problem yourself, and update your question with your `code trials`, as-is your question is just looking for feedback, and may not fulfill SO standards of a **Programming Questions**. Please look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Try https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html